# SAS Enterprise Guide automation schedule with connection?

Tags: authentication, vbscript, automation, sas

I have made vbs to run project and generate report on windows cmd, but the machine should be logged in single sign on tool bar.

My question is, windows schedule task does not include SAS log in information. Any way to put login information in vbscript? or any other way to include login so that i don't have to logged use tool bar before hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'-------------------
'Log on using Profile
'-------------------
' Set to your metadata profile name, or "Null Provider" for just Local server
app.SetActiveProfile("My Profile")
```